# How can i get the wires to follow my Cloth sim?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

How do i get these Wires to Follow my rigged cloth sim?
[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E9EpR8wCr4Z1J2c0flk4EgsOLXEJ_BJB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds like a job for hook modifiers. See if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFIRWRaVWlw) YT video helps.

Comment: I actually followed that YouTube video to make this. The only thing is that I want to have the wires I already made follow the cloth sim. I do not want to remodel them.